# Unable to build c code in visual studio code

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw-w64

1) using tmd-gcc
2) path is set

[getting These errors while trying to Build the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpVus.png)

Comment: You're going to get downvotes for putting a link in description.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't post images of text, copy-paste it as text instead.

Comment: As for your problem, the letter `&` have special meaning for some command-line shells, and need to be escaped (with a backslash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very bad idea to have `C&C++` directory. Rename it to `C_CPP` for example and everything will work OK

Generally speaking try to avoid any non ASCII chars in the paths and filenames when programming. Even if theoretically speaking system allows them, the tools (like compilers, linkers etc) used in development might not.